# Set radgrid row background color dependant on bound column

Tags: radgrid

I would like to configure my RadGrid to show a icon or perhaps a different row colour when a activity flag in the bound row is set to true.

Can I do this in JS?

Basically I have a grid of data bound to a entity statement in code behind. One of the columns is TicketActivity and when set to true I would like the gridrow to show an icon (red dot or something) or change the background colour of the grid row.

Comment: Are you binding your grid in client side or server side?